# removing element by counting in a list-Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
lst=['a','b','c','a','d']
count=0 
for item in lst:
```

Is there a way so that i can count each index in the list and when the count!=1 i remove that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is order important? If not, you can use Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
unique = [val for val, i in Counter(lst).items() if i == 1]
```

If order is important you can use the unique list (or set as below) to filter out duplicates, eg.:

```
from collections import Counter
unique = {val for val, i in Counter(lst).items() if i == 1}
result = [val for val in lst if val in unique]
```

Or if even Counter is not available, you can make your own Counter:

```
counter = {}
for val in lst:
    counter[val] = counter.get(val, 0) + 1
```